# Workflow HELP: Sharepoint designer 2010 template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

On SP 2013 with SPD 2010 workflow template
My need is the following when a document is uploaded in a document library:

1. a topic (subject) is created in a discussion board with the name of the document
2. workflow updates a field in document library called link, writing the link (url) of the discussion thread related to the original entry. Possibly with the hyperlink of the thread, but if not possible I would have enough of the text version of the url

I have done successfully point 1. Need assistance for point 2 since I get confused a lot with the value field of SPD workflow engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer to my above question: my workflow steps worked and were technically correct, but the 2 actions needed to be separated by a 1 minute pause because the system was not fast enough to catch up the first action to then create the second.

I thought just by the fact that the second action started with 'THEN' that there was a pause in itself to wait for the previous action to finish, but it wasn't.

So I added in the middle a pause and my workflow works.